# Image source is getting deleted after uploading new image to Flask using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I have method to upload images to Flask in JavaScript. Below is the code used to upload images and display text in chatbot. This is used in my Chatbox class on button click:

For text there is no issue, it's working fine. However when uploading an  image, previously uploaded images are getting deleted, ie. the previous `img` tag `src` is not visible in the DOM inspector.

```js
var i = 1;
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('question', $("#question").val());
formData.append('questionImageFile', $("#question-image")[0].files[0]);

let question_id = $("#question").val();
let question_image_file = $("#question-image")[0].files[0];
let msg1;

if ($("#question").val() === "" && $("#question-image")[0].files[0] === "")
  return;  
else if ($("#question").val() != "")
  msg1 = {
    name: "User",
    message: question_id,
    timestamp: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
  }
else {
  var imgMsg = '<img id="' + i + '"/>'
  msg1 = {
    name: "User",
    message: imgMsg,
    timestamp: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
  }
}

this.messages.push(msg1);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/chatbot",
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: (result) => {
    let msg2 = {
      name: "Sam",
      message: result.response,
      timestamp: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    };

    this.messages.push(msg2);
    var html = '';
    
    this.messages.slice().reverse().forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (item.name === "Sam") {
        $("#question").val() + '</div>' + '<div class="chatbotResponse"><div class="timeBot">' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + '</div>' + result.response + '</div>'
        html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' + '<div class="timeBot">' + item.timestamp + '</div>' + item.message

        if (item.message.startsWith("Sorry, I")) {
          html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="feedbackBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Go to feedback form</button>'
        }

        html += '</div>'
      } else {
        html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' + '<div class="timeUser">' + item.timestamp + '</div>' + item.message + '</div>'
      }
    });
    
    const chatmessage = chatbox.querySelector('.chatbox__messages');
    chatmessage.innerHTML = html;
    if (formData.get('questionImageFile')) {
      console.log(i)
      var output = document.getElementById(i);
      output.src = window ? .URL ? .createObjectURL(formData.get('questionImageFile'));
      i = i + 1;
    }
    // $("#question").val()
    $("#question").val("");
  },
  error: function(result) {
    alert('error');
    this.updateChatText(chatbox)
    $("#question").val("");
  }
});
```

Comment: `chatmessage.innerHTML = html` will overwrite *all* existing content in the `chatmessage` element. I would presume you want to append the content instead - `+= html`

Comment: In that case text also should delete but its not

Comment: So you're saying that it's literally just the `src` attributes which are set to empty values - the previous `img` elements still exist in the DOM?

Comment: Yes .if inspect to previous image tag src attribute only wont be there